# How to set XLang in Leon online system,Is it possible?

Tags: scala, leon

I want to verify following code

```
object Test {

    def test(a: Int): Int = {
      require(a > 0)

      var sum = 0
      var i = 0

      while(i < a) {
        sum = sum + i
        i = i + 1
      }

      return sum
    } ensuring(res => res=a(a-1)/2)
}
```

Please help me how I can use Leon online system to verify the above code

Getting following compilation Error

10:Mutable variables (e.g. 'var x' instead of 'val x') require xlang desugaring

14:Mutating variables requires xlang desugaring

9:Mutable variables (e.g. 'var x' instead of 'val x') require xlang desugaring

13:Block expressions require xlang desugaring Mutating variables requires xlang desugaring

12:Block expressions require xlang desugaring While expressions require xlang desugaring

Comment: Simply paste it there, and you will get an error message. It's not valid code of course, as the top-level class or object is missing.

Comment: Check the compilation error you got then..

Comment: Getting following compilation Error       10:Mutable variables (e.g. 'var x' instead of 'val x') require xlang desugaring
 14:Mutating variables requires xlang desugaring
 9:Mutable variables (e.g. 'var x' instead of 'val x') require xlang desugaring
 13:Block expressions require xlang desugaring
Mutating variables requires xlang desugaring
 12:Block expressions require xlang desugaring
While expressions require xlang desugaring

Comment: @Tom Fix your code then. Or ask in a forum. But StackOverflow is not for fixing broken code.

Comment: @Madoc The code is perfectly fine ..showing output in scala compiler ....it is not working in leon ....which is a verification loop ...its online version i am not able to verify above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you pasted has a few other issues, I'll assume it's a copy/paste error since the errors you are reporting are different, but here the fixed version:

```
object Test {
  def test(a: Int): Int = ({
    require(a > 0)
    var sum = 0
    var i = 0
    while(i < a) {
      sum = sum + i
      i = i + 1
    }
    sum
  }) ensuring(res => res == a*(a-1)/2)  
}
```

Of note, you were using an assignment in the ensuring clause, and you should not use `return` along with `ensuring` as Scala would just shortcut the ensuring and directly return from the function. In general, don't use `return` in Leon, and I'm going to also advise to not use `return` with Scala in most cases. Also you had `a(a-1)` which is not valid Scala code for a multiplication, you should have `a*(a-1)`.

Now, about the `--xlang` option for Leon online. The code you are trying to verify relies on imperative programming (vars and loops) and the support in Leon for imperative programming comes from a module called `xlang`. Unfortunately, `xlang` support was desactivated from Leon Online, as it behaves quite poorly with the synthesis features of Leon. We are working on improving the `xlang` module so that it can be run along with the rest of the features of Leon. Hopefully this should happen eventually.

In the meantime, your only option, if you wish to verify programs using imperative features such as the above, is to run Leon from the command line with the `--xlang` option:

```
./leon --xlang Test.scala
```

You can find some documentation on how to install Leon on your system here: https://leon.epfl.ch/doc/installation.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for detail explanation. It is working thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @Regis Blanc I tried the above program, if the postcondition we give is incorrect, Leon gives a counterexample quickly; if the postcondition is correct, it does not terminate.